# Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Tags: php, apache, https, openssl, xampp

The problem is in the question. I've done a thorough investigation for solutions in regards to this and I know there are topics to this and I've followed them too and nothing has worked. That being said I'll list out exactly everything I've done so far. I am running PHP 5.2.14 with Zend Debugging on the latest Eclipse version on my Windows XP computer. I have a 1 GB of RAM. I have XAMPP running with Apache, MySQL, and FileZilla installed.

On XAMPP I've done the following (Apache was off during these changes):
Clicked on *Admin* from the XAMPP Control Panel and went to `https:// localhost/xampp/`. From there I accepted the certs from this line on the welcome page:

> For OpenSSL support please use the test certificate with https:// 127.0.0.1 or https:// localhost.

On that same section I checked `phpinfo()`. Under 'Environment', `SERVER["HTTPS"]` is `on`. Under 'Apache Environment', `HTTPS` is `On`. Under 'PHP Variables, `_SERVER["HTTPS"]` is `On`. Under 'Phar', `OpenSSL support` is `disabled` (install ext/openssl). I don't know how to enable the Phar one.

Now regarding the files themselves in C:\xampp, I went to the PHP folder. Under both production and development php.ini files (better safe than sorry), I have `allow_url_fopen=On`, `allow_url_include=On`, and I removed the semicolon, so that `extension=php_openssl.dll` is no longer commented out. I even confirmed that the .dll is in the ext folder of the PHP folder. Both libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll are in the PHP and Apache folders. The Apache folder doesn't contain either productive or development php.ini files.

I've went to http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html and installed Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.0d for safe measure.

Now the line of code in question in my retrieve_website.php looks like this:

```
$urlquery = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=".$appid."&cx=".$google_searchid."&q=".$query."&alt=atom&num=".$results;
$xmlresults = file_get_contents($urlquery);
```

I have two other websites that I query but they are served via HTTP and they work fine. I also have this line of code entered near the end of the script:

```
echo 'openssl: ',  extension_loaded  ('openssl') ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'http wrapper: ', in_array('http', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'https wrapper: ', in_array('https', $w) ? 'yes':'no', "\n";
echo 'wrappers: ', var_dump($w);
```

When I run it as a PHP Script on Eclipse, everything outputs perfectly fine the way I want along with these results:

```
openssl: yes
http wrapper: yes
https wrapper: yes
wrappers: array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "https"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "ftps"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "php"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "file"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "data"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "http"
  [6]=>
  string(3) "ftp"
  [7]=>
  string(13) "compress.zlib"
  [8]=>
  string(14) "compress.bzip2"
  [9]=>
  string(3) "zip"
}
```

Despite all these changes I've made (after I started up Apache), I still get the same errors the first time I access my PHP script in Eclipse and Firefox via http://localhost/tutorial/retrieve_website.php:

> Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\retrieve_website.php on line 29
>   Warning: file_get_contents(https:// www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=*removed API ID*&cx=*removed search ID*&q=The+Devil+went+down+to+Georgia&alt=atom&num=5) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\retrieve_website.php on line 29
>   Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Empty string supplied as input in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\retrieve_website.php on line 33
>   openssl: no http wrapper: yes https wrapper: no wrappers: array(10) { [0]=> string(3) "php" [1]=> string(4) "file" [2]=> string(4) "glob" [3]=> string(4) "data" [4]=> string(4) "http" [5]=> string(3) "ftp" [6]=> string(3) "zip" [7]=> string(13) "compress.zlib" [8]=> string(14) "compress.bzip2" [9]=> string(4) "phar" }

What is it that I have overlooked or failed to do? To my own knowledge, I've done everything that I've researched about concerning HTTPS and OpenSSL

Answer (score 198):

I solved it in XAMPP by uncommenting `;extension=php_openssl.dll` in `/apache/bin/php.ini` *despite* phpinfo() telling me `/php/php.ini` was the loaded ini file.

**EDIT:** I guess Ezra answer is the best solution directly adding the extension line to the appropriate ini file.

Comment: Are you sure that its `/apache/bin/php.ini` , I cannot find it in XAMPP Portable Light 1.8.1? However `php/php.ini` exists, but enabling ssl here does not help :(

Comment: this answer would then create another problem because openssl is now disabled and will throw an error if I get_file_contents a secured link

Comment: For me it was `xampp/php/php.ini` :) thanks , PS: DONT FORGET TO RESTART APACHE AFTER SAVING CHANGES

Comment: There's no php_openssl.dll, it's just openssl.dll.

Answer (score 103):

I had to add `extension=php_openssl.dll` to my `php.ini` file located in `xampp/php/php.ini`. Somehow it was not there, after adding it and restarting Apache everything was working fine.

Comment: I had to add the line, as it was not in php.ini - but then did the trick - thanks!

Comment: There's no php_openssl.dll, it's just openssl.dll.

Answer (score 37):

just add two lines in your php.ini file.

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
allow_url_include = On
```

its working for me.

Comment: I'm using wamp and you need to edit the php.ini in the apache folder rather the the usual one in the PHP folder :O

Comment: Thank you, it was the `allow_url_include = On` that solved it for me.

Comment: Do not enable allow_url_include — this brings your server vulnerable.

Comment: There's no php_openssl.dll, it's just openssl.dll.

Comment: in version 7 it is just openssl

Answer (score 18):

Your Apache is probably not compiled with SSL support. Use cURL instead of file_get_contents anyway. Try this code, if it fails then I am right.

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $curl = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  $data = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: ran that curl function you gave me and replaced `$xmlresults = file_get_contents($urlquery);` with `$xmlresults = curl($urlquery);`. PHP Script ran it just fine with the same results as file_get_contents(). Running it as PHP Web Page via http://localhost/tutorial/retrieve_website.php and I get this error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorial\retrieve_website.php on line 14`

Comment: Problem is probaby in SSL support, run **phpinfo()** and check if there are following commands/flags: `'--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr'`, basically you need to compile Apache with SSL support, you should also enable cURL that is couple times faster than FGC, and has numerous options. I have no idea how to do this on Windows, sorry.

Comment: only thing close to that is Configure Command at the top of phpinfo() and that doesn't have anything containing --with-openssl related. it contains other --with things. small update: on localhost, checked status and it says HTTPS (SSL) is activated.

Comment: If you invoke `return curl_exec($curl);`, wouldn't that prevent `curl_close($curl);` on the next line from executing?

Answer (score 13):

I have enable the openssl extention and it work for me :)

**;extension=php_openssl.dll**

to

**extension=php_openssl.dll**

Comment: There's no php_openssl.dll, it's just openssl.dll.

Answer (score 12):

I got this error while attempting to install composer using php cli on Windows. To solve it, I just needed to change the extension directory in `php.ini`. I had to uncomment this line:

```
; On windows:
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Then this one and all things worked

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;...
extension=openssl
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case (PHP 7.3 on Windows in FastCGI mode) it was uncommenting `extension=openssl`.
Not *extension=**php_**openssl*, as most people post here.

(The same thing was [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49661841/589600), but without details on OS which may be a key difference here.)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the issue was due to WAMP using a different php.ini for CLI than Apache, so your settings made through the WAMP menu don't apply to CLI. Just modify the CLI php.ini and it works.

Comment: Wel how did you did it where can I find the CLI php.ini

Comment: Mine is located here: `C:\path\to\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\php.ini`

Comment: thanks for your answer, I thought there where multiple php.ini files. When I searched I only found one and I uncommented: ;extension=php_openssl.dll But I use xammp I confused it with wamp. Now it works, yeah!

Answer (score 6):

in OpenSuse 12.1 the only thing required was:

```
zypper in php5-openssl
```

Comment: can you explain please??

Comment: I mean I got the error message "Unable to find the wrapper “https” - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?" and resolved it by entering "zypper in php5-openssl" at the command line. That fixed the error.

Answer (score 5):

On MAC AMPPS, I updated the php-5.5.ini with the following and now it works.

```
allow_url_include = On
extension=openssl.so
```

Answer (score 5):

PHP7, in php.ini file, remove the ";" before `extension=openssl`

Comment: This is not enough to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

For me I had to uncomment these lines in php.ini:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension_dir = "ext"
```

"ext" is applicable if php_openssl.dll is located in the "ext" folder.

**Note:** I had to do this for **two** of my php.ini files otherwise it would not work. One located in the vs.php installation folder, and the other on on the PHP folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jcx.Software\VS.Php\2013\Php 5.6
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6
```

[Source](http://www.herongyang.com/PKI/HTTPS-PHP-Configure-PHP-OpenSSL-on-Windows.html)

Comment: There's no php_openssl.dll, it's just openssl.dll.

Answer (score 4):

On newer versions of PHP on Windows, the majority of answers here won't work, since the corresponding configuration lines have changed.

For PHP 7.x, you need to uncomment (remove the `;` at the beginning of the line) the following lines:

`extension_dir = "ext"`
`extension=openssl`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function instead if curl is installed on your system:

```
function get_url_contents($url){  
  if (function_exists('file_get_contents')) {  
    $result = @file_get_contents($url);  
  }  
  if ($result == '') {  
    $ch = curl_init();  
    $timeout = 30;  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);  
    $result = curl_exec($ch);  
    curl_close($ch);  
  }  

  return $result;  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem with file_get_contents for the requests https **in Windows**, uncomment the following lines in the php.ini file:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Comment: There's no `php_openssl.dll`, it's just `openssl.dll`.

Comment: in version 7 it is just openssl

Answer (score 2):

After snooping around all day, I figured out the answer thanks to this guide:
http://piwigo.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=15727

Basically under Eclipse -> Windows -> Preferences -> PHP Executables, there is a section on where the .exe and .ini is referenced. The defaulted ones were in the Eclipse directory when you install the PHP Development Tools SDK Feature from Eclipses Install New Software in the Help menu.

So instead of that, I added a new executable called PHP 5.3.5 (CGI) and referenced the cgi.exe and .ini from xampp's php folder.

Thank you webarto for giving your time to help me out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using opsenSUSE Leap, and I had the same issue -- it means there's no support for OpenSSL. This is how I resolved it:

1. Open YaST.
2. Go to Software Management.
3. In the search box on the left pane, enter 'php5-openssl' and press the return key.
4. Click the checkbox next to 'php5-openssl' in the right pane to select it, and click 'Accept' (This adds OpenSSL support).
5. Restart Apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`

That's it, you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error too. I figured out that my version of PHP didn't have openssl compiled in, so simply adding the extension directive to php.ini wasn't enough. I don't know how you have to solve this in your particular case, but for me, I use macports, and the command was just:

```
sudo port install php5-openssl
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using [Winginx](https://winginx.com/en/) (nginx based instead of Apache based), I fixed it with these 4 steps:

1. On the *Tools* menu hit the *Winginx PHP5 Config* (never mind the **5** in the name...):

   [image: Winginx PHP5 Config]
2. Select the PHP version you want the *php.ini* to change:

   [image: PHP version selection]
3. On the *PHP Extensions* tab select the **php_openssl** extension and hit the *Save* button:

   [image: php_openssl selection]
4. restart the appropriate PHP service through the taskbar (*Stop* and *Start*):

   [image: Restart PHP service]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wamp server then go to icon click on this [image: wamp server icon click on this]

Then go to PHP then click on PHP extension there would be php_openssl need to activate from there and restart wamp server [image: active php_openssl from here]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on Windows. Enabling the `extension=openssl` and `extension_dir = "ext"` lines in `php.ini`, was not enough to fix the issue.

I also had to add the `C:\php\` folder to Windows environment path.
This is because openssl module need to load some dlls (eg: libcrypto) which are located in php installation folder.

What helped me while troubleshooting this was to check the `error.log` file in `\apache24\logs\` folder. There you will get explicit messages if openssl module cannot be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the `https` request and after a little bit of time messing with my php.ini files I tried just changing the link to `http`. It works just change the download link and you shouldn't need to enable anything.

The changes that people made to PHP7 probably do work but I am using PHP 8.3. If someone know how to fix it for the php.ini-development and production files, I would love to see comments on it!

Answer (score -1):

Inside the *simple_html_dom.php* change the value of the `$offset` variable from `-1` to `0`. 
this error usually happens when you migrate to *PHP 7.*

`HtmlDomParser::file_get_html` uses a default offset of `-1`, passing in `0` should fix your problem.