# downloading facebook image to local server

Tags: php, facebook, image, image-uploading

i am using

```
function save_image($inPath,$outPath){
    //Download images from remote server
    $in=    fopen($inPath, "rb");
    $out=   fopen($outPath, "wb");
    while ($chunk = fread($in,8192))
    {
        fwrite($out, $chunk, 8192);
    }
    fclose($in);
    fclose($out);
}
```

This function working perfectly , but if i open the image it show file is empty.

i also tried file_get_content() function .But still having the same problem.

Comment: Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: yes Unable to find the wrapper "https"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config)

Comment: i have uncommented the extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini but still getting same error

Comment: @NathanSri - Did you restart Apache (or whatever is running your PHP process)?

Comment: yes i did, but still getting same error

Comment: @NathanSri - I'd advice taking a look at the second answer on that question then -- use the curl functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always prefer to use curl to do this kind of thing.

```
function saveImage($url, $savePath) 
{

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $fp = fopen($savePath, 'wb');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    fclose($fp);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;

}
```

If you don't have curl installed check the official PHP [curl installation instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php), installing curl of Windows is pretty easy.