# Make an API call in PHP without using Curl

Tags: php, api, curl

I want to make the following API call in PHP:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&filter=%28any+type%3A%2Fcvg%2Fcomputer_videogame%29
```

How can I do so without using curl?

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP method: `file_get_contents()`: https://www.php.net/file_get_contents

Answer (score 1):

This returns json. You should use `json_decode()` and `file_get_contents()` for this.

Example:

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&filter=%28any+type%3A%2Fcvg%2Fcomputer_videogame%29");

$json = json_decode($file, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($json);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: I used your code but I got this message: ( ! ) Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper &quot;https&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 128

Comment: Then you want to change your php.ini file to accept SSL. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config

Comment: I did that but now I get this message: Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&amp;filter=%28any+type%3A%2Fcvg%2Fcomputer_videogame%29): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 128

Comment: That's not an issue with your code; it's an issue with Google. Their APIs have request limits and may fail if the parameters are rejected. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits#http403

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple GET request, file_get_contents can do that reasonably well :

```
$return = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&filter=%28any+type%3A%2Fcvg%2Fcomputer_videogame%29');
```

Provided you can process the return body (depends on content-type), and do not need to process errors/special http headers/authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Use "`file_get_contents`" with the right configuration.

http://fr.php.net/file_get_contents

Comment: I tried this but I got this warning/error:  Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?indent=true&amp;filter=%28any+type%3A%2Fcvg%2Fcomputer_videogame%29): failed to open stream: Result too large

Comment: Take a look at the server configuration.