# How to get GitHub raw file contents with PHP?

Tags: php, github

I am browsing Github info/docs but cant find any simple example on how to 
get contents of a raw Github file.

For example if I try to use

```
$url ="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/master/index.html";

echo file_get_contents($url);
```

I get `failed to open stream: HTTP...`

If I use `curl` same thing 404 page. So obviously I have to use API but there is just no simple example on how to do it. 
Can someone please post plain example. 
Thank you!

Comment: Worked fine for me. Can you show the full error message.

Comment: stupid ssl , http://stackoverflow.com/a/7123591/594423, thnx , but curl still fails

Comment: curl fails because you need to specify the option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `false` for `curl_setopt`

Comment: please post it as answer. that was it. thank you!

Comment: add standard security considerations for doing curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740933/security-consequences-of-disabling-curlopt-ssl-verifyhost-libcurl-openssl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different method to escape SSL validation and add more options if you want, with CURL function.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/master/index.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

Works fine for me here, you just need to enable, if was not, the curl extension.

Comment: add standard security considerations for doing curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740933/security-consequences-of-disabling-curlopt-ssl-verifyhost-libcurl-openssl