# Installing Composer for Windows - unable to find wrapper "https"

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

I am trying to install Composer for Windows using the command line with the following call:

php -r "readfile(https://getcomposer.org/installer);" | php

However, I get this error message:

Warning: readfile(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when configured PHP? in Command line code on line 1

Call Stack:
   0.0010  224336 1. {main}() Command line code:0
   0.0010  224488 2. readfile() command line code:1

Warning: readfile(https://getcomposer.org/installer): failed to open stream: invalid argument in Command line code on line 1

Call Stack:
   0.0010 224336 1. {main}() Command line code:0
   0.0010 224488 2. readfile() Command line code:1

I have already uncommented the ";extension=php_openssl.dll" line in the php5.5.12 directory, restarted the browser, and tried other variants. When I run the command with just the 's' in https dropped, I get:

Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly. Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible. If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

I've tried including this --with-openssl flag at various places but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config)

Comment: all of the answers in that post are addressing something which I've already done, which is uncomment the line in the php.ini file on "extension=php_openssl.dll"

Comment: Have you restarted the server after doing that?

Comment: yes, I already tried that

Comment: I know this is really old. Just want to tell future readers what my fix was. 
The line "extension=php_openssl.dll" wasn't in my php.ini file. I had it

Answer (score 12):

This sounds like your installation hasn't got openssl enabled.

Locate your `php.ini` file (on Windows this is probably in the same place as the `php.exe` (`c:\php` on my machine).

Open it in your favourite editor, and locate the line

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

remove the semi-colon

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

HTTPS should now work for you from within php.

Answer (score 7):

It works by using Havenard's answer. Just add '..' to enclose the url

```
php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --disable-tls
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, since the solution doesn't seem to work for you for whatever reason, you can observe that all this command is doing is download the file and printing it into another `php` process. This is a rather simple problem that can be workarounded with minor adaptations.

You can for instance, drop `https` and use `http`:

```
php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --disable-tls
```

Or let some other tool fetch this file, such as:

```
wget -s -O - "https://getcomposer.org/installer" | php -- --disable-tls
```

Or even:

```
curl -sSk "https://getcomposer.org/installer" | php -- --disable-tls
```

The option `--disable-tls` is relevant to the `installer` script, it will tell it to use `http` instead of `https` in the furter downloads it will perform during the installation.

Comment: result of the first one: parse error: syntax error, unexpected : in command line on line 1

Comment: @AdamF You are either not copying the exact same line or you are typing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Windows 10, PHP 7.3.24) it was

```
extension=openssl
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/63460807/7508553)