# symfony not work on windows server 2008

Tags: php, symfony

i have trying to install symfony  but i have no luck.

what i have did :

- i have look at internet.
- i have set the path of php.exe
- i have move
  symfony into the folder that contains php.exe

  but still, when i run symfony on command line, it said that 'symfony' not recognize.....

[image]

**EDIT:** now i follow the sugestion, but i got  [image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not put the symfony installer in the php folder. Place it somewhere else e.g. in your home folder so that it is not deleted upon upgradeing php.

Make sure php.exe is in your PATH variable.

Add or uncomment the following extension in your php.ini file:
`extension=php_openssl.dll`

then run the command `php symfony` again.

Comment: i move the symfony into C:\THE_Symfony, as you can see on my image that php.exe is in my path variable. and my php.ini , the line extension=php_opensslLdll is already uncommented....as i try php symfony...i got warning: readfile() unable to find wrapper.....

Comment: maybe this kind of duplicate can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201815/installing-composer-for-windows-unable-to-find-wrapper-https