# Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony

Tried to create a symfony project and got an error.

So I entered in the console:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project
```

console output:

```
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
Your configuration does not allow connections to http://packagist.org/packages.json. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-
config.md#secure-http for details.
http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of da
te

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/p/symfony/website-skeleton%24e4840857811b44fdd2effbe71a2cd41d6c17c10fe4f92248daacc2c4e0c
  ecd67.json" file could not be downloaded: Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you
   configured PHP?
  failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249620/the-openssl-extension-is-required-for-ssl-tls-protection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this solution, it might help you:

[Installing Composer for Windows - unable to find wrapper "https"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201815/installing-composer-for-windows-unable-to-find-wrapper-https)

It seems that you do not have openssl enabled in your php