# Soap service with an ssl certificate with password (PHP)

Tags: php, ssl, soap, wsdl, codeigniter-2

I need to access a SOAP service with a certificate protected by password. I'm new in PHP (with PHP 5.4 in CodeIgniter 2) and have tried some options that doesn't work for me.

I have the following constants:

```
const WSDL  = 'https://sedeapl.dgt.gob.es:8080/WS_IEST_COMP/descargaArchivoMicrodatosService?wsdl';

const XMLNS = 'https://sedeapl.dgt.gob.es:8080/WS_IEST_COMP/descargaArchivoMicrodatosService';

const LOCAL_CERT_PASSWD = 'HERE I HAVE THE PASS OF THE CERT';
const LOCAL_CERT = './certificados/Certificados.p12';

private $client;
```

I have tried these options:

**Option A**

```
$this->client = new SoapClient(self::WSDL, array(
                "trace"         => 1, 
                "exceptions"    => true, 
                "local_cert"    => self::LOCAL_CERT, 
                "uri"           => "urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes",
                "style"         => SOAP_RPC,
                "use"           => SOAP_ENCODED,
                "soap_version"  => SOAP_1_2 ,
                "location"      => self::XMLNS
            )
        );
```

**Options B**

```
$this->$client = new SoapClient(self::WSDL, array('local_cert' => self::LOCAL_CERT));
```

I have no idea how to add the password. Those solutions are what I found here on StackOverflow. In both examples I get the same error:

> SoapClient::SoapClient(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you
>   forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

I have uncomented the "extension=php_openssl.dll" in php.ini

I've tried with these routes of cert:

```
const LOCAL_CERT = 'certificados/Certificados.p12';
const LOCAL_CERT = 'Certificados.p12';
const LOCAL_CERT = './certificados/Certificados.p12';
```

Does anyone have an idea about what can I do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all you need to convert .p12 to .pem
in Linux you can do it with following command
`openssl pkcs12 -in Certificados.p12 -out Certificados.pem -clcerts`

then try the following:

```
$options = array();

$options['trace'] = true;
$options['exceptions'] = true;
$options['local_cert'] = 'path to your .pem file';
$options['passphrase'] = self::LOCAL_CERT_PASSWD;

try {
    $soapClient = new SoapClient(self::WSDL, $options);

    echo '<pre>';        
    // wsdl methods
    print_r($soapClient->__getFunctions());        
    echo '</pre>';
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage(), '<br />', $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

Comment: now I have Certificados.pem in:
Proyect
  Source Files
    application
      certificados
        Certificados.pem
      controllers
        Controller with the code to access the service

is correct this path?
$options['local_cert'] = './certificados/Certificados.pem';

I stil having errors:

Message: SoapClient::SoapClient(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Message: SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://sedeapl.dgt.gob.es:8080/WS_IEST_COMP/descargaArchivoMicrodatosService?wsdl"

Comment: @Noark did you restart your web server after enabling php_openssl? also try to file_get_contents(self::WSDL);

Comment: Yes I restarted Apache in XAAMP server. 
With 
    file_get_contents(self::WSDL); 
I have two errors:

Message: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Message: file_get_contents(https://sedeapl.dgt.gob.es:8080/WS_IEST_COMP/descargaArchivoMicrodatosService?wsdl): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Could be that the WSDL isn´t working? here there is the offitial doc:

https://sedeapl.dgt.gob.es/IEST_INTER/MICRODATOS/webService/IEST_descargaFicheroMicrodatos.pdf

But in spanish... (It have the wsdl)

Comment: so, at first you have to solve this issue. openssl is not enabled yet. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config?rq=1 maybe it will help you

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that.

Comment: It seems like my apache does not load the extension openssl, but I don't know why. I have in php.ini this two lines: 

extension=php_openssl.dll
allow_url_include = On

and in httpd.conf this one:
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

And when I ask for extension_loaded with openssl It does not load.

Comment: @Noark what OS? do you use XAMPP or WAMP or something?

Comment: I use XAMPP server and win 7 (with codeigniter 2, php 5.4 and .Net Beans 8.1)

Comment: @Noark so, when you restart apache is everything fine? do you have php_openssl.dll in \xampp\php\ext directory? what phpinfo says about loaded php.ini?

Comment: yes I have the .dll in that path. I restart XAMPP without problems:

12:43:14  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
12:43:21  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
12:43:22  [Apache]  Status change detected: running

In php.info (I didn't know that it exists) I have in section Loaded Modules many modules and this one mod_ssl  

I have related to ssl this;

Apache Version Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.8
SSL Version OpenSSL/1.0.2d
and more stuff with ssl.

But I have this one disabled:
OpenSSL support disabled (install ext/openssl)

Can be formated this comments?

Comment: @Noark loaded php.ini file I meant look for string Loaded Configuration File

Comment: I tried to conect it to ISS and it works with your code. There might be any kind of problem with Xampp and ssl, but in production I have ISS so no problem. The solution you give me for conect the certificate with password works perfect on ISS. Thanks you very much.