# Error in PHP on https wrapper

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am getting the following error and I am hosting the a local server using WAMP and using version 5.6.19 of PHP

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did
>   you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Comment: What is unclear in the error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you can try is to:

Install php5-openssl
Restart Apache afterwards.

It will likely to solve that problem.

And there's also another possible solution:
You can find the "php.ini" file, and open it, you will find the line: extension=php_openssl.dll And is there a semicolon at beginning? If yes, simply delete it and it will work.

If that doesn't work or you have further issues, comment me and I will help you! :)

Comment: Sorry but I am using PHP server and not Apache

Comment: So you are using WAMP on Windows Right?

Comment: What you can try is to delete the ; mark before extension=php_openssl.dll in PHP.INI if you are under Windows Environment

Comment: Yes Wamp on Windows

Comment: What you can try is to delete the ; mark before extension=php_openssl.dll in PHP.INI if you are under Windows Environment

Comment: Here's one possible solution: So you can find the "php.ini" file, and open it, you will find the line: extension=php_openssl.dll     And is there a semicolon at beginning? If yes, simply delete it and it will work.

Comment: If it helps, you can mark my answer as "Accepted" Thanks for doing that!

Answer (score 5):

You need to enable `php-openssl` in your WAMP.

For this, click on the WAMP icon in your systemtray. Click on PHP. Then hover the `PHP Extensions`. Then click on the `php_openssl`