# JSON response through URL not displaying

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

Hi I have a page link with json data.
I wanted to fetch them from url.
I tried below code. But that not working for me.

```
<?php
echo $URL1 = "https://www.the-worldwide.com/wp-content/themes/thewebconz/Live-6-cid/functions.php";
    $vars1 = "action=Hotel_Description&hotel_id=438271&cid=457428&apiKey=5jjdvgnq9aug1a4ucvatvq4b8u&ModeType=Live&secret=9hs897nn3e9av";
$URLs_Fetch1 = $URL1."?".$vars1; 

        $json = file_get_contents($URLs_Fetch1);

$data = json_decode($json,true);

$Geonames = $data;

echo "<pre>";

print_r($Geonames);     
?>
```

But if you normally visit that page you can see many json data there.

https://www.the-worldwide.com/wp-content/themes/thewebconz/Live-6-cid/functions.php?action=Hotel_Description&hotel_id=438271&cid=457428&apiKey=5jjdvgnq9aug1a4ucvatvq4b8u&ModeType=Live&secret=9hs897nn3e9av

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/728824)

Comment: You can do using your json object

Comment: The error you get is pretty obvious, not? **Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?**

Comment: @Deep is there any way I can print full json response data? It will help me to parse data from resource.

Comment: @OfirBaruch Bro my site link is that https://www.the-worldwide.com/ How can I make it http:// I have to use https://

Comment: You can either change your code (use cURL) or update your php configuration (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9791203/998096)

Comment: @OfirBaruch I used curl method too. https://eval.in/728830 that also not working.

Comment: Your PHP is missing the cURL extension. You need to install it (http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php)

Comment: @LemonKazi have you checked my answer and tried that?

Comment: Actually the output from the given url is not a valid json response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use jsonlint to validate the response of the url directly from browser you will find that the output is not a valid json response. hence you are unable to decode it. All you need to do is remove html tags which are hidden and hotel_id content and and issues with new lines . After solving those issues it becomes a valid json response. and there you go.

```
<?php
$base_url = "https://www.the-worldwide.com/wp-content/themes/thewebconz/Live-6-cid/functions.php";
$data = [
    "action" => "Hotel_Description",
    "hotel_id" => 438271,
    "cid" => 457428,
];
$config = [
    "apiKey" => "5jjdvgnq9aug1a4ucvatvq4b8u",
    "ModeType" => "Live",
    "secret" => "9hs897nn3e9av"
];
function buildUrl($base_url, $data, $config)
{
    $url = $base_url."?";
    $data_uri = "";
    foreach ($data as $data_key => $data_value) {
        $data_uri .= "$data_key=$data_value&";
    }
    $config_uri = "";
    foreach ($config as $config_key => $config_value) {
        $config_uri .= "$config_key=$config_value&";
    }
    $url= $base_url."?".$data_uri.rtrim($config_uri, "&");
    unset($data_uri);
    unset($config_uri);
    return $url;
}
$url = buildUrl($base_url, $data, $config);
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$new_content = str_replace("<HotelInformationRequest><hotelId>".$data['hotel_id']."</hotelId><options>0</options></HotelInformationRequest>", "", $content);
$json_content = str_replace("\n", " ", $new_content);
```

Comment: thanks bro. u are right. the output data was not as json response. i solved that. thanks.

Comment: Whoever down voted please take out your precious time to mention the reason

Answer (score 0):

Install php5-openssl Restart Apache afterwards. There is already an answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639676/error-in-php-on-https-wrapper) about this,

if not worked then add `extension=php_openssl.dll` to your `php.ini` file located in `xampp/php/php.ini` or `wamp\path to php.ini` file.

i.e. just add two lines in your php.ini file.

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
allow_url_include = On
```

If these will not help you out then please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Deep for answer. I am trying it from my end. I will let you know soon. :)