# Symfony 3 new project error

Tags: php, symfony

I start a tutorial about Symfony 3 and I'm facing an issue when creating a new project with this command :

```
php symfony.phar new Symfony
```

I have this error :

```
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]
  Error creating resource: [message] fopen(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when y
  ou configured PHP?
  [file] phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/symfony.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 406
  [message] fopen(https://get.symfony.com/symfony.version): failed to open stream: Invalid argument
  [file] phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/symfony.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 406
  [message] Undefined variable: http_response_header
  [file] phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/symfony.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 407






  [GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException]
  Error creating resource: [message] fopen(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when y
  ou configured PHP?
  [file] phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/symfony.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 406
  [message] fopen(https://get.symfony.com/symfony.version): failed to open stream: Invalid argument
  [file] phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/symfony.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 406
  [message] Undefined variable: http_response_header
  [file] phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/symfony.phar/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 407
```

I have PHP7 installed locally, is it possible it's the source of the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config

Answer (score 3):

Probably as per @0x13a 's comments you don't have openssl installed.

I think in XAMPP these are the instructions:

Go into your `C:\xampp\php\ext\php.ini` file and uncomment:

> ;extension=php_openssl.dll

If not, try adding it. I believe XAMPP should have openssl installed, but if not, you might need to look into that.

---

Edit #2 - For Marine1

Use this command to install openssl:

```
sudo apt-get install openssl
```

Then find out which php.ini is being used vi php from command line:

```
php -i |grep 'Loaded Configuration File'
```

Then edit the above specified php.ini with vi (below is an example):

```
vi /etc/php.ini
```

And make the changes I indicated.

Comment: Hi Nathan30. If this fixed the problem, can you click the checkmark to mark this as the answer. There are 2 ways to respond to an answer, one way is to click the up arrow if the answer helped, the other is the checkmark to indicate it solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: And what about users of Linux  ? ;)

Comment: Hi @Marine1, what distro of Linux do you have? My answer address the OP's question which is on Windows.

Comment: @Marine1 See my Edit #2 section (just for you). By the `16.04` is not a distro, but instead you should have called it `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`. Thanks!

Comment: @Marine1, `vi` is the standard text editor that has been around since the 1970's (at least). You can instead use nano editor, or whatever is available on your distro. For example `nano /etc/php.ini`.