# Error on https even if I enabled openssl

Tags: php, easyphp

I'm trying to do a simple script like this with `easyphp` installed on my pc:

```
<?php
include_once ('C:\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php713vc14x86x170802204733\simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/summer/1896/');
echo $html;
?>
```

I enabled in php.ini the php_openssl extension but I still get the error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did
>   you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in
>   C:\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php713vc14x86x170802204733\simple_html_dom.php
>   on line 75

What else could I do?

---

I have this from phpinfo:

[image]

I tried to put php.ini files into c:\windows but it still does not work.

Comment: Are you sure you enabled it in the correct `php.ini` file? There are nomally 2. Look at the output of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to see where the `php.ini` file is located that PHP under Apache is using

Comment: ok, I enabled it under easyphp dir but running php.info I see that php.ini file is located on C:\windows :-(. I have to change this path or copy a php.ini from easyphp dir to c:\windows?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-to-work-with-https