# Getting a weird php error when im trying to connect to google sheets api

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So I am getting this weird error whenever I try to connect to google sheets using php. I tried googling it but I cant figure it out. Does anyone have some suggestions?

Edit: Thanks for the quick replies, I just added the code.I don't know why it's throwing an error because I literally just copied and pasted this from the google documentation.

CODE:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

// Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
// https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
$spreadsheetId = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms';
$range = 'Class Data!A2:E';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();

if (empty($values)) {
    print "No data found.\n";
} else {
    print "Name, Major:\n";
    foreach ($values as $row) {
        // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
        printf("%s, %s\n", $row[0], $row[4]);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\Users\Desktop\Payment Website\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 67
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in C:\Users\\Desktop\Payment Website\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:187
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\\Desktop\Payment Website\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection()
#1 C:\Users\\Desktop\Payment Website\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError()
#2 C:\Users\\Desktop\Payment Website\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish()
#3 C:\Users\\Desktop\Payment Website\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke()
#4 C:\Users\\Desktop\Payment Website\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(51): in C:\Users\\Desktop\Payment Website\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187
```

Comment: You need to post the code that gets the error.

Comment: The error indicates that something that should be an array is something else.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the quick reply i just made an edit.

Comment: What line are you getting the error at? (where line 67 corresponds to?)

Comment: @lamblichus i managed to fix it, i believe the error was being thrown outside of my code but inside some other framework file i had downloaded, because i was trying to connect up to google sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out if you follow this, it should help. Personally i didn't use apache or anything like that.

[Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config)

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because the curl verifies and makes a secure connection request using self-signed certificate. When it does not find the valid certificate, it throws an error.
To fix this error, follow the steps below:

1. Open http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Copy the entire page and save it as a "cacert.pem"
3. Open your **php.ini** file and insert or update the following line.

   curl.cainfo = "[pathtofile]cacert.pem"

Comment: can i insert that anywhere into the php.ini file

Comment: @ItIsN3RD Search for curl.cainfo in the php.ini file and you will find it .Thanks.

Comment: i didnt see it.

Comment: says cant find curl

Comment: You need to enable the curl extension.