# installing composer2 on Ubuntu 20.04. there is https error on the command: php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"

Tags: php, laravel, https, openssl, composer-php

I'm trying to download composer from official site, the error that I'm getting is:

> Warning: copy(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget
> to enable it when you configured PHP? in Command line code on line 1
>
> Warning: copy(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget
> to enable it when you configured PHP? in Command line code on line 1
>
> Warning: copy(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget
> to enable it when you configured PHP? in Command line code on line 1
>
> Warning: copy(https://getcomposer.org/installer): Failed to open
> stream: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1

I've already tried uncommenting `extension=openssl` in `php.ini`

Comment: make sure you modify the correct ini file, php-cli and php for apache use two seperate php.ini files. Type `php --ini` in your terminal to know which ini file your `php-cli` uses

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config)